# Is there a way to get details about a process in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, powershell, taskmanager

I want to know alternative for the `/proc/[pid]/status`, `stat`, etc. in Windows. I know there is Task Manager but it does not show things like kernel mode time, user mode time,etc. At least I don't know how to see those. Is there a way so check such details about processes in Windows? I tried Cygwin but it doesn't give all pids of all the running process, only 2-3 are there in the proc "directory" in cygwin. So, if there is a way please tell it to me.

Comment: have you looked at `Get-Command *process*` yet?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey what do I have to put in *process*? Name or id?

Comment: @ShantanuShinde If you open a PowerShell prompt and just run `Get-Process` it will show some default information about the running processes.  To see everything that it retrieves (since it doesn't show it all by default), try this: `Get-Process | Format-List *`.  An alternative is to query the performance counters, using [Get-Counter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: @ShantanuShinde - please use the built in help system for that. it is really _quite_ useful. [*grin*] try `Get-Help Get-Process` for more info ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PowerShell, you use the `Get-Process` cmdlet to get information about one or more processes running on the system. If you run the cmdlet without any parameters, it will list all processes. You can also use the process name (without extension):

```
Get-Process wmplayer
```

Alternatively, you can specify a process id, like so:

```
Get-Process -id 25024
```

By default, PowerShell will only display some of the properties on an object returned from a cmdlet like `Get-Process`. To see all properties and their values, pipe the output into the `Select-Object` cmdlet, like so:

```
Get-Process wmplayer | Select-Object *
```

Here, kernel mode time and user mode time (for example) will show as `PrivilegedProcessorTime` and `UserProcessorTime`, respectively. For more info about `Get-Process`, read [`Get-Help Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-6). If you're new to PowerShell, it should be noted that there are aliases for common cmdlets, which makes them less verbose:

```
gps wmplayer | select *
```

---

If you're looking for a GUI tool for inspecting processes, then I would recommend [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), which is substantially more powerful than Task Manager, and will show you much more detailed information about processes and the system in general:

[image: procexp]